# Create a specific formula using elements from a string

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have two strings:

1) $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17$

2) $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20$

and each strings is divided into $3$ substrings.

For the first string we have the following substrings:

$\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, $\{6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ and $\{12,13,14,15,16,17\}$

For the second string we have the following substrings:

$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\{7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ and $\{14,15,16,17,18,19,20\}$.

I want to create an equality relation depending about the last number from the string.

For example, for the first string I would like to have a variable *i* which is going from $0$ to 17 and helps me to obtain value $3$ when *i* takes the values from the first substring, $4$ when *i* takes the values from the second substring and $5$ when *i* takes the values from the third substring.

The same story when for the second substring.

Here is a short example about what I'm trying to do:

$1+\frac{i+2}{9}$ and this expression is equal with $1$ when *i* goes from $-1$ to $6$. Is equal with $2$, when *i* goes from *7* to $15$ and $3$ when *i* goes from $16$ to $24$. Let's say that is a step of $9$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> For example, for the first string I would like to have a variable *i* which is going from $0$ to 17 and helps me to obtain value $3$ when *i* takes the values from the first substring, $4$ when *i* takes the values from the second substring and $5$ when *i* takes the values from the third substring.

$3+\left\lfloor\frac i6\right\rfloor$ works where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ :

- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i6\right\rfloor=3$ for $i=0,1,\cdots, 5$
- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i6\right\rfloor=4$ for $i=6,7,\cdots, 11$
- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i6\right\rfloor=5$ for $i=12,13,\cdots, 17$

> The same story when for the second substring.

$3+\left\lfloor\frac i7\right\rfloor$ works :

- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i7\right\rfloor=3$ for $i=0,1,\cdots, 6$
- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i7\right\rfloor=4$ for $i=7,8,\cdots, 13$
- $3+\left\lfloor\frac i7\right\rfloor=5$ for $i=14,15,\cdots, 20$